# document.getElementbyID and looping

Tags: javascript

```
<body> 
    <div id="page"> 
    <img id="slot0" class=slot src="crab.gif" width="120" height=80>
    <img id="slot1" class=slot src="sun.gif" width="120" height=80>
    <img id="slot2" class=slot src="sail.gif" width="120" height=80>
```

Below I want to use y to replace 0, 1 & 2

```
var slotValues = new Array(3);
var slots = new Array ('0','1','2');

for (y=0;y<=slots.length;y++){

slotValues.push (document.getElementById("slot" + slots[y]));}
```

But IE said `document.getElementById("slot" + slots[y])` is not an object though I think it is and if I change `slot[ y]` to 0, it can find but it is not being dynamic.
Could you please check where I went wrong.

Comment: Did you bother re-reading your question before posting it? It's a big unreadable mess.

Comment: Probably you need to replace `y<=slots.length` with `y<slots.length`

Comment: For next time, don't forget to look at other questions, at the faq, and at the help you have in the question edition toolbar.

Comment: And its document.getElementById not ELEMENTS. Looks like you haven't been using enough javascript. (I am referring to the title)

Comment: Where do you have this script in your document (a function, inline etc) and how do you test for `slot[0]`? It seems that the document is not fully loaded when you execute the script.

Comment: Besides the `<=` problem, worth mentioning is that your `slotValues` array will have 6 elements after the code executes. You have to (1) either assign the values to `slotValues[y]` in favor of `push()` or  (2) initialize the array with `var slotValues = new Array(0);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> IE said it is not an object. but it is

Rather believe the one who knows the DOM.

Your problem seems to be that your `for (y=0;y<=slots.length;y++)`-loop iterates 0, 1, 2, and 3, since `3 < slots.length` - yet your array has only 3 items and `slots[3]` is `undefined`. Change your loop to

```
for (var y=0; y<slots.length; y++) {
```